# Simple query gone wrong

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I must be having an off day. This should be obvious but I don't get it.

```
-- check for necessary updates to dbnotes
select count(distinct table_name) 
from ccsv4.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
```

returns 46

```
select count(distinct table_name) 
from dbnotes
```

returns 44

```
select distinct table_name 
from ccsv4.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
where table_name not in (select distinct table_name from dbnotes)
order by table_name
```

returns nothing

```
select distinct table_name 
from dbnotes
where  table_name not in (select distinct table_name 
                          from ccsv4.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS])
order by table_name
```

returns nothing

What am I missing guys?

Comment: what is `dbnotes` and this structure ?

Comment: what is `ccsv4` ?

Comment: Without seeing the data of the first two queries (without the distinct), how can we (or you) know they overlap? Please post sample data and/or schema

Answer (score 1):

You are using `not in`.  If any value from the subquery is `NULL`, nothing will be returned.

With a subquery, *always* use `not exists`.  It has the right semantics:

```
select distinct table_name
from ccsv4.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] c
where not exists (select 1
                  from dbnotes d
                  where d.table_name = c.table_name 
                 );
```

I am pretty sure that tables have to have at least one column, so you might as well use `information_schema.tables` instead.  It saves you the `distinct`:

```
select table_name
from ccsv4.information_schema.tables t
where not exists (select 1
                  from dbnotes d
                  where d.table_name = t.table_name 
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks guys. For those who asked, CCSv4 is the database, DBNotes is the table. Also, there are 46 column names in the database and 44 in the notes table. I am using the notes table to document the tables of the database. The overlap is all 44 column names (rows) already in the notes table. I expected 2 rows to be returned when selecting from information_schema NOT IN dbnotes.  I'll try the different syntax suggestions.